# jQuery Tools Validator: not required, but test if not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-tools

I'm using [the Validator from jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/) to validate my form (why jquery tools? because they are lightweight and use semantic HTML5 Tags, input-types and params for validation) but I have one problem:
I want to let jQuery Tools Validator test/validate a input-field only if it is not empty — but the field is not required.

On fields that have to be tested/validated, I can use `required="required"` and it validates … now I have a text-input-field where the user can input a URL, this field is not required BUT if the user adds some data into that field, the field should validate with `pattern="https?://.+"` to get sure the user is entering a valid url... if I add the pattern-parameter and no required-parameter, jQuery Tools Validator does test/validate nonetheless and I'm not able to submit the form until I entered a valid URL — even if I do not want to enter a URL at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try modifying your regex to allow the empty string, such as

```
pattern="^(?:|https?://.+)$"
```

Comment: yeah! thx! btw: jQuery Tools Validator do not neet ^ and $, their 'included' … so pattern="(?:|https?://.+)" works! Thank you, toby!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you're tied to jquery tools validator? I've had great success with : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

So for example I'd add a custom jQuery validator field:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("unittype", function(value, element) { 
    return jQuery('#fuel option:selected').val() in unitOptions && value in unitOptions[jQuery('#fuel option:selected').val()];
});

jQuery('#fuel').rules("add", {
    fueltype:true,
    messages:{
        fueltype:"Please select a fuel type"    
    }
});
```

That was just an example from my code, just substitute the regex into the method.

Comment: thx … I choosed validator because it's lightweight, it has extended css-posibilities, it uses standard html5-input-types for general validation … and it's easy to use. :-) but thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify your form field as

```
<input type='url'/>
```

then jQuery Tools Validator will require a valid url--you shouldn't need to roll your own url regex.

And if you don't mark that field required, then the validator should only check the field when it's non-empty; which, if I understood correctly, is the behavior you (OP) want.